# Reacting Grignard reagent with esters to excusively produce a ketone

Tags: organic-chemistry, esters, grignard-reagent

Adding 2 moles of grignard reagent to an ester, gives out 2 alcohols. But, if 1 mole of grignard reagent is added, will the reaction exclusively produce a ketone? How to prepare a ketone in a reaction only with esters and grignard reagent as starting materials?

CH2=CH2-C(=O)OCH3 + CH3MgBr -> CH3-CH2-CH=C=O + CH3OH

Is the above reaction possible?

Comment: I would presume the answer to be $$\ce{CH2=CH-CO-CH3}$$ which is a ketone

Comment: No, you'll get a mixture. If you want a ketone then the standard way is to react the Grignard with a Weinreb amide RCONMe(OMe)

Comment: @Waylander So, is it impossible to isolate the ketone from reacting grignard and ester alone, irrespective of the no. of moles?

Comment: In $\ce{CH3-MgBr}$, magnesium increases the electron density toward the methyl group a lot. While it is *not* a salt like NaCl, you may assume that when it comes into contact with water (intentional during workup), the methyl group will react like a Lewis base to abstract (like a Bronsted base) a proton from water to yield $\ce{CH4}$, rather than to yield MeOH. This is one reason why, *beside* Grignard reagents, other organometallic reagents which are less basic (in terms of $pK_a$) are *equally* in use today.  Note, acidity (thermodynamics) is different from nucleophilicity (kinetics).

Comment: If you recall general reactivity scales of aldehyde *vs.* ketone *vs.* ester *vs.*  amide against a nucleophilic attack on the $\ce{C=O}$ group, you recognize that the ketone is much more susceptible to the reaction of the Grignard than the initially submitted ester.  Thus the advantage of the Weinreb amide *even if* it may require some extra work.

Comment: @Boson  It is impossible to get a decent yield of ketone from Grignard + ester. As @ Buttonwood states, any ketone you form is more reactive then any ester that would still be present.